# Get cell value by address string in Numbers

Tags: numbers

In Numbers 3.5.2 I manage to get a cell address sting (I compute it based on some data). Now when I have it, how can I get the value behind that address without copying the result of my function to the another cell and adding `=` before it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the **INDIRECT** function, which returns the contents of a cell or range referenced by an address specified as a string.

example:

```
INDIRECT("B2")
```

---

Here's [Apple](http://www.apple.com/mac/numbers/compatibility/functions.html) documentation about Numbers.app functions.